# Fastest way to grow up a NumPy array from another NumPy array containing selection indices

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have to create a big array from a known one by using a set of indices of the original array. The indices are stored as a ndarray, and to build up the new array I am doing something like this:

```
import numpy as np

dim_1       = 200
high_index  = 1000 
dim_2       = 300

masks_array = np.random.randint( low = 0, high = high_index - 1, size=(high_index, dim_1) )
the_array   = np.random.rand( high_index, dim_2 )

new_array   = np.array( [ the_array[ masks_array[ j, : ], :  ] for j in range(high_index) ]  )
```

Is this the fastest way to generate the new_array from the masks_array? Is there a way to do this without a loop? And out of interest, since the "for" loop is inside the np.array constructor, does this translate into efficient looping in Python (similar to list comprehension)?

Comment: To summarize, you want to create a new matrix, from `the_array` using the indices given in `masks_array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [198]: dim_1       = 200
     ...: high_index  = 1000
     ...: dim_2       = 300
     ...: 
     ...: masks_array = np.random.randint( low = 0, high = high_index - 1, size=
     ...: (high_index, dim_1) )
     ...: the_array   = np.random.rand( high_index, dim_2 )
     ...: 
     ...: new_array   = np.array( [ the_array[ masks_array[ j, : ], :  ] for j i
     ...: n range(high_index) ]  )
In [199]: new_array.shape
Out[199]: (1000, 200, 300)
In [200]: masks_array.shape
Out[200]: (1000, 200)
In [201]: the_array.shape
Out[201]: (1000, 300)
```

Let's try the simple indexing with the `masks_array`:

```
In [205]: arr = the_array[masks_array,:]
In [206]: arr.shape
Out[206]: (1000, 200, 300)
In [207]: np.allclose(new_array, arr)
Out[207]: True
```

Time comparisions:

```
In [213]: timeit new_array = np.array([the_array[masks_array[j,:],:] for j in ra
     ...: nge(high_index)])
658 ms ± 17.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [214]: timeit arr = the_array[masks_array,:]
292 ms ± 65.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The time savings are modest, I suspect because of the large overall size of the result.

This is python, and `np.array` is a function.  So

```
[the_array[masks_array[j,:],:] for j in range(high_index)]
```

is evaluated first, and then passed to `np.array.

```
In [215]: timeit [the_array[masks_array[j,:],:] for j in range(high_index)]
369 ms ± 7.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```